# PowerShell query for active users before executing action

Tags: powershell

### Intro:

First off, I am very new to scripting in general so the logic behind how I think this should be solved may likely be flawed. I am working with Windows Server 2012 R2 so I figure that PowerShell might be the best approach for this.

### What I am trying to do:

Set a scheduled task to run once an evening and call a script that does the following:

1. Check to make sure there are zero active users logged in to the local server that is executing the script

   - Users in a disconnected state would NOT count as logged in.
2. If zero active users:

   - Logoff any actual users (not system processes) that are in a disconnected state
   - Delete C:\MyFolder\*
3. Else, do nothing

The idea is that I don't want to delete C:\MyFolder, but I want to delete the contents within it. I might not be able to delete the contents within C:\MyFolder if a user that is in a disconnected state is the one who owns the contents so to get around that, I log them off (they shouldn't be leaving disconnected sessions anyways).

### Logic:

After doing some reading around, I found that `qwinsta /server:localhost` seems to query the localhost for users and provide this type of output:

```
PS C:\Users\EF112131> qwinsta /server:localhost
SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
services                                    0  Disc
console                                     1  Conn
                  AB123456                  2  Disc
rdp-tcp#0         cd789101                  3  Active
rdp-tcp#1         EF112131                  4  Active
rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen
```

That gives me the logged on users that I care about (`AB123456`, `cd789101`, and `EF112131`) and it checks the respective state of their sessions (`Disc`, `Active`). My thought is that from here I can pull in the `USERNAME` and `STATE` into some sort of check. If the check returns any `STATE` set to `Active`, the script will do nothing and end. If there are no `Active` states, the script will disconnect any `USERNAME` that is in a `Disc` state and then clear the contents of C:\MyFolder by doing something like `del /S C:\MyFolder\*`

The issue I am having here is that I have no idea how to pull those values from the above output? I would imagine it is something similar to how `awk` is in Linux land but I still haven't figured it out.

Comment: I would consider looking at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29130697/3829407) which converts qwinsta output into a PowerShell object. Makes it easier to query the data.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2012 R2 + Powershell 4.0 = No more text parsing!

Have a look here Url: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj215451(v=wps.630).aspx

and use the following commands to query

1. Query the users: Get-RDUserSession
2. Log off the user ID which is disconnect with Invoke-RDUserLogoff

Regards,
Glenn