# Get current Windows session ID in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Every Win32_Process object contains a SessionId field. What is the simplest way to get the current Windows session ID in PowerShell? By current I mean the session in which the script is running. I'd like to avoid parsing the output of the `query session` command. If that's not achievable, is it possible to list all processes in the current session?

Comment: I would also be curious but if you get stuck you can use my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29130697/3829407) to parse the data from `qwinsta` into a PowerShell object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
(Get-Process -PID $pid).SessionID
```

Comment: Looks like SI is an alias property for that.  `(Get-Process -PID $pid).SI`

Answer (score 9):

You can

```
PS C:\Users\AlexK> [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().SessionId
1
```