# Converting txt file as HTML in Powershell Send-MailMessage

Tags: html, powershell

I have log file created from a batch process in the below format.

```
Step DateTime            Description

#0   09/12/2016 17:02:20 TestTableCount.ps1 started from step 1
#1   09/12/2016 17:02:21 The table etl.ProcessLog is Empty . Failed
```

I want to add this to the body of the email using `Send-MailMessage` in PowerShell.

I wrote a code that converts the text file to HTML and adds it as a table in the body of the mail.

Code:

```
$body = Get-Content $LogFile | out-String

$body = $body -replace '^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)', '<tr><th style = "border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px;">$1</th><th style = "border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px;">$2</th><th style = "border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px;">$3</th></tr>'
$body = $body -replace '\n(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)', '<tr><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">$1</td><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">$2</td><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">$3</td></tr>'
$body = '<body><table style = "border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">' + $body + '</table></body>'
```

But that is resulting in the below format:

[image: This is the result from my code]

I want the sate and time to come under the DateTime column, but from the code I have written I am getting the time under Description.

How to correct this and get the proper format?

Comment: Since you are generating this log file, why not generate it as a .csv and get much of what you are doing for free?  Then you can use a style for your table as well and not embed this into a complicated replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell works better with objects so I am going to suggest something other than building a html file from strings and regex.

While the code I am going to present might seem tedious is works more efficiently and can be easily tailored for other tasks. The first part of this code comes from [my answer to another question about parsing fixed width data from a test file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29130697/3829407). The second is a simple showing of how `ConvertTo-HTML` works. The former is required to take advantage of the latter. Assume that the file "C:\temp\Test.txt" is your log file and replace as needed. Same for output file path at the end of this snippet.

```
# Convert the fixed width left aligned file into a collection of psobjects
$data = Get-Content C:\temp\Test.txt | Where-Object{![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}

$headerString = $data[0]
$headerElements = $headerString -split "\s+" | Where-Object{$_}
$headerIndexes = $headerElements | ForEach-Object{$headerString.IndexOf($_)}

$results = $data | Select-Object -Skip 1  | ForEach-Object{
    $props = @{}
    $line = $_
    For($indexStep = 0; $indexStep -le $headerIndexes.Count - 1; $indexStep++){
        $value = $null            # Assume a null value 
        $valueLength = $headerIndexes[$indexStep + 1] - $headerIndexes[$indexStep]
        $valueStart = $headerIndexes[$indexStep]
        If(($valueLength -gt 0) -and (($valueStart + $valueLength) -lt $line.Length)){
            $value = ($line.Substring($valueStart,$valueLength)).Trim()
        } ElseIf ($valueStart -lt $line.Length){
            $value = ($line.Substring($valueStart)).Trim()
        }
        $props.($headerElements[$indexStep]) = $value    
    }
    [pscustomobject]$props
} 

# Build the html from the $result
$style = @"
<style>
    body{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse}
    th{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px}
    td{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px}
</style>
"@

$results | Select-Object $headerElements | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style | Set-Content c:\temp\test.html
```

Notice that I converted your style in the code above. The resulting file would look like this as html:

[image: rendered table]

The columns are out of order but it is nothing a simple `Select-Object` could not fix.

Answer (score 0):

Date and time are separated by a space, which is matched by the second `\s+` in your second regular expression.

Change

```
$body = $body -replace '\n(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)', '<tr><td ...'
```

to

```
$body = $body -replace '\n(\S+)\s+(\S+ \S+)\s+(\S+)', '<tr><td ...'
```

and the replacement should do what you expect.