# Kubectl Namespace script to filter only name

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, namespaces, kubectl

I'm trying to use Kubectl get namespaces command it is fetching the data.

```
kubectl get namespace
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   1d
kube-node-lease   Active   1d
kube-public       Active   1d
kube-system       Active   1d
```

but I want to filter it with name only. So when u run the script it should show like this.

```
kubectl get namespace
NAME              
default           
kube-node-lease  
kube-public       
kube-system
```

I've tried some powershell command but it is not working out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any one of the command

```
kubectl get namespace --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'
```

```
kubectl get namespace | awk '{print $1}'
```

```
kubectl get namespace --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"
```

```
kubectl get namespace -o=name |  sed "s/^.\{10\}//"
```

Comment: This works for me, however, can you please suggest where I can find more such commands, this will help me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the output of `kubectrl` is pure text so to manipulate it you will need to either do text parsing (error-prone and not fun) or you need to get the data into a PowerShell object.

[ConvertFrom-SourceTable](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable)

This will allow you to read and parse the text/string data into a PowerShell object. Then you can simply `Select-Object name` to get the Name column only.

The second option is to use text/string parsing but for that, you will have to use length detections to extract the columns. An example of that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47335781/extract-columns-from-text-based-table-output).

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
kubectl get ns | awk '{print $1}'
```