# Delete specific line from variable

Tags: powershell

I'm making a PowerShell script that will list the number of users currently logged on to a system.

What I do is the following:

```
$users = query user /server:localhost
$number = $users.Count

if ( $number -le 1 ) {
    Write-Host 0 Users online"|" Users=0
} else {
    $number = $users.Count-1
    Write-Host $number Users online"|" Users=$number
}
exit
```

However I need to be able to exclude users, such as the Administrator.

I thought I could make an `if` statement but I don't know how to do this properly really.

Lets say I do it like this:

```
$users = query user /server:localhost

if ($users -contains '*Administrator*') {
    $number = $users.Count-2
    Write-Host $number
}
exit
```

I add the `.Count-2` because the first line is the information such as "Username, ID, Session" etc.

It doesn't return anything so I don't think I can make an `if` statement like that.

Is it possible to "grep" something from the `$users` variable and delete that line?

For instance, if I run:

```
$users[1]
```

It will return the second line etc. But how do I manipulate the lines?

I also tried:

```
$users | Where-Object {$_ -match 'administrator'}
```

But that returns nothing.

Does anyone have any input here on what I could do?

Comment: Try `$users | Where-Object {$_ -notlike "*Administrator*"}`

Comment: Holy crap that was fast. That actually worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem :) Need a greater explanation or figured it out yourself?

Comment: I think I can figure it out from here. That was the piece I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: You might consider it overkill but [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29130697/38294070) should convert that output to  a customer powershell object. Its what I use for converting text based output like what you have.

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't return anything so I don't think I can make an `if` statement like that.

You can make an `if` statement roughly like that, but what you can't do is use:

```
'some words test' -contains 'words'
```

as the test. This is because `-contains` is for this use:

```
@('collection', 'of', 'words', 'here') -contains 'words'     # if a collection contains X.
```

For text inside a string, you need one of the following:

```
'some words test' -like '*words*'   # this is a wildcard match, case insensitive.

#or

'some words test' -match 'words'    # this is a regex match, case insensitive.

#or

'some words test'.Contains('words')    # this is a .Net method on strings, case sensitive.
```

Comment: OR just use the string method `.Contains()`...  `'some words test'.Contains('words')`  The `-contains` operator is intended to be used against collections.

Comment: FYI Contains method is case sensitive which can screw things up